# Managing page paths in ASP .NET application

Tags: asp.net

Currently in my web application I have plenty of lines like this:

```
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

etc. Now, I'm in the process of reorganizing aspx pages structure, as it's pretty flat - everything is in one folder. So I have to thoroughly search all the code in order to fix aspx paths. So my question is: is there any way to manage/organize web site pages structure in ASP .NET - some kind of SiteMap, so that I have a code similar to:

```
            Response.Redirect(Pages.Default);
```

so that my code will be closed for modifications where some aspx pages are moved between folders?

Comment: have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/176342/Strong-Typed-Response-Redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written an open source project that will help you, http://navigation.codeplex.com/.

You list your pages and transitions in a config file. Here's an example:

```
<state key="Page1" page="~/Page1.aspx">
    <transition key="Next" to="Page2"/>
</state>
<state key="Page2" page="~/Page2.aspx"/>
```

Then in your code you can move from Page1.aspx to Page2.aspx like this:

```
StateController.Navigate("Next");
```

Let me know if you're interested or need any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there there's any automatic solution, you'll probably end up building something yourself. You may want to check out the Asp.Net Sitemap stuff, although it's mainly focused on Navigation controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx

I ran into the same issue you're facing on a few projects. One simple solution is to create constant/static/enums to represent the page names/urls:

```
public static class SiteMap {
    public static readonly string Default = "/default.aspx";
}
```

which of course lets you do

```
Response.Redirect(SiteMap.Default);
```

But that was outgrown quickly as the pages required parameters passed in, and sooner or later you run into exactly the same problem with the parameter names. So we expanded on that idea by adding an Url factory class like

```
public static class SiteMap {
    public static readonly string Article = "/blog/article.aspx";
}

public static class PageParams {
    public static readonly string ArticleId = "aid";
}

public static class UrlFactory {
    public static string GetUrlBlogArticle(int articleId){
        return string.Format("/{0}?{1}={2}",SiteMap.Article, PageParams.ArticleId, articleId.ToString());
    }
}
```

That approach ensures all the links work the same way and include the same parameters. By setting up a PageParams constants class the landing pages/controls code are a little cleaner too, since you can do

```
public void method(){
    var articleId = Request[PageParams.ArticleId];
}
```

rather than have random request parameter names everywhere.

Hope that gives you some ideas.